# Remove nodejs with Conda in JupyterLab

Tags: node.js, jupyter, conda

I installed nodejs in my virtual environment in JupyterLab with `conda install -c conda-forge nodejs`
Now I'm trying to uninstall Nodejs with Conda, but after I run `conda remove nodejs` (or with conda-forge) I get this error:

```
    ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - python=3.1
```

Python version I have is 3.10.2 (with this version I installed nodejs too). Anybody knows why is this happening?